# How can I change the text field size of number value entered?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

This is my UI for a registration form. As you can see the text-fields which entered number value (Service_fee, Supplier_price, Total) are hiding the half on entered value. I used bootsrap to design this UI. And I tried by changing txtfield's class property by using input-large. 
**  **
  
But still complete value is not showing.. :( 
Given below is my code. Please help me..

```
     <body>

           <div class="container">
             <form action="MobilePhoneRepairing.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                <h1 class="font">Mobile Phone Registration</h1>          
          <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="span10" >
                <div class="control-group form-horizontal">
                    <p>
                        <label class="floated" for="sdate"><b>Select Date :</b></label>

                        <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated" for="model_no"><b>Model no :</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="model_no" id="model_no" class="input-medium" placeholder="Enter Modle No" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated" for="service_fee"><b>Service fee :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="service_fee" id="service_fee" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated" for="sp_name"><b>Supplier name :</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sp_name" id="sp_name" class="input-medium" placeholder="Enter Supplier name " />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated" for="sp_price"><b>Supplier price :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="sp_price" id="sp_price" class="input-medium"  onkeyup="doMath();"/>
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated" for="description"><b>Description :</b></label>
                        <textarea class="textarea" name="description" rows="2" cols="12" placeholder="Enter item description"></textarea>
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated " for="total"><b>Total :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="total" id="total" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>
                        <label class="floated"> &nspar; </label>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn-info " name="save_data" value="Save" id='savedata'  />
                        <input type="reset" class="btn-primary " name="reset" value="Reset Form" id='reset' />
                        <br class="clear"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If Rafa's answer, below, doesn't work for you, please edit [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d62zW/) and re-create your problem. Then click UPDATE and post the new jsFiddle URL into your question, like this:  `[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d62zW/)`

Comment: @gibberish  thank you for your answer.. :) But I coludn't find the change you did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS to add a customized height:

```
.input-medium{
   height: 35px;
}
```

If this doesn't wok for you, try using "!important":

```
.input-medium{
   height: 35px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just a note to try to avoid using `!important` as much as you can.

Comment: Of course @sbeliv01 you are right! I told as the last option!

Comment: @To both of you guys. can you please tell me why important is not a good option?

Comment: The “!important” suffix was originally intended to provide a method of overriding author stylesheets. It applies to ALL the styles rules except inlines rules so it's a bit dangerous. The most of the times you can replace the "!important" word with an specific selector rule. Here you are the W3C definition for selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Please @Dilini mark que question as correct to help other users!